# How to transfer data to a serial port?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me, serial-port

I know that in J2ME `CommConnection` is the connection to use when working with `serial port`. I know there are the `openInputStream` and `openOutputStream` methods , but in fact I don't know how to transfer data from my MIDLet to the COM port ( the USB port into which the phone's cable is inserted , the phone is Alcatel OT-806D ). For example I want to send the text "Hello world". How to achieve that ?

Here are codes :

**J2ME :**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.CommConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class SerialPortMidlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener, Runnable {
    private Command upload = new Command("upload", Command.SCREEN, 0);
    private Command exit = new Command("exit", Command.SCREEN, 1);
    private Form f = new Form("test serial port");
    private Thread uploadThread;
    private CommConnection com;
    private OutputStream os;
    public SerialPortMidlet()
    {
        f.addCommand(upload);
        f.addCommand(exit);
        f.setCommandListener(this);
        uploadThread = new Thread(this);
    }
    public void startApp() {
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(f);
    }
    public void pauseApp() {
    }
    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        if (c == upload)
        {
            uploadThread.start();
            f.removeCommand(upload);
        }
        else if (c == exit)
        {
            if (uploadThread.isAlive())
            {
                uploadThread.interrupt();
                try {
                    uploadThread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            destroyApp(true);
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            String s = new String("andrana mandefa lavaka");
            com = (CommConnection) Connector.open("comm:COM4");
            os = com.openOutputStream();
            os.write(s.getBytes());
            os.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**J2SE :** ( Eclipse )

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
public class TwoWaySerialComm 
{
    public TwoWaySerialComm()
    {
        super();
    }
    void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
    {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
        if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
        }
        else
        {
            CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

            if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
            {
                SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

                (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

                serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));
                serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
            }
        }     
    }
    public static class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener 
    {
        private InputStream in;
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
        {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
            int data;

            try
            {
                int len = 0;
                while ( ( data = in.read()) > -1 )
                {
                    if ( data == '\n' ) {
                        break;
                    }
                    buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
                }
                System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }             
        }

    }
    public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
    {
        OutputStream out;

        public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
        {
            this.out = out;
        }

        public void run ()
        {
            try
            {                
                int c = 0;
                while ( ( c = System.in.read()) > -1 )
                {
                    this.out.write(c);
                }                
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-1);
            }            
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            (new TwoWaySerialComm()).connect("COM1");
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I run the J2SE program , I inserted the mobile phone cable into the computer ( in the USB slot ) , I clicked the `upload` command in the J2ME app , but there is nothing in the output screen of the eclipse !

So what's the problem ?

I run this J2SE code to detect the port on which the phone's cable is :

```
import gnu.io.*;
public class SerialPortLister {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listPorts();
    }
    private static void listPorts()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        java.util.Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while ( portEnum.hasMoreElements() ) 
        {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();
            System.out.println(portIdentifier.getName()  +  " - " +  getPortTypeName(portIdentifier.getPortType()) );
        }        
    }
    private static String getPortTypeName ( int portType )
    {
        switch ( portType )
        {
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_I2C:
                return "I2C";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                return "Parallel";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RAW:
                return "Raw";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_RS485:
                return "RS485";
            case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                return "Serial";
            default:
                return "unknown type";
        }
    }
}
```

And it shows COM4 because when I detach the cable then only COM1 and LPT1 are displayed.

So what's the problem ?

Comment: In Mobile you can find only COM1 or COM2 only, while this ports are always busy in computer system for other purposes.

Comment: But I discovered that COM4 is the port used by the phone !

Comment: that is a good sign. only just you need to search the file in the computer system. It must be there in some directory. Or you can give a physical path in your J2SE Code.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone seems to be well detected by the computer as connected on the virtual COM port 4. However, this is not clear to me that you should use the COM port protocol on the phone side to communicate with the computer. It is perfectly possible that there is simply a buffer on the phone, that once filled will be delivered on the usb port.

I don't know your phone but I have already programmed a microcontroller. There I was never using the COM port protocol and managed to communicate with a computer with virtual com port driver.

To understand better my point, you can probably refer to documentation of the microcontroller present on your phone.

Comment: The phone is Alcatel OT-806D. Is a `microcontroller` a virtual com port `driver` ?

Comment: The [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) is the main chip of your phone, the equivalent of a microprocessor for a phone.

Comment: The problem is that the J2ME application I am developping is to be sold as a project : I am working in an informatic service company ; it should work for any kind of phone device. So how to make the transfer always established ?

Comment: It might be a typo in your pasted code but from what I understand the serial port on the phone is COM1 or COM2 or whatever and the port on the computer is COM4. Shouldn't you use COM4 in j2se and COM1 in j2me?